# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 via the Windows installer

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows

**Hello,**
**If I install Ubuntu 13.04 using the windows installer, will it overwrite my windows?**

I am asking this because I like the freedom of Ubuntu, but I want Windows just in case 
**thanks :)**

Comment: Installing via the "windows installer" is **not** an option available for 13.04. If you want Windows, do a proper side-by-side installation to have a dual boot..

Comment: Here patched 14 version. It works, i tried. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Incase you're still looking, [here's the WUBI Installer for 13.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/raring/wubi.exe). For all other Ubuntu releases [see here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/).

Comment: dead link. 404.

Comment: @emrah I have updated the link.

Comment: Thanks. But i have found patched 14 version and worked. here you go. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

no if you use wubi (the windows installer) it will install in the free space (it makes a very large file and installs it in there). This is the case for me. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi. edit.  There is no support for  wubi for 13.04. In which case it isn't necessary to installed an earlier  version and upgrade. http://schoudhury.com/blog/articles/install-ubuntu-13-04-with-ubuntu-wubi-installer/

Comment: The OP has asked about **13.04**. AFAIK, Wubi isn't available for 13.04. So your answer isn't appropriate at least for this particular question.

Comment: Ah. Because there was a wubi.exe in the 13.04 release I thought it did. Sorry. Editing to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

install ubuntu 10.10  and than upgrade it because you can mount 10.10  over windows using demon tools it has a option to install ubuntu over windows and you give the specific space and also no need create bootable usb or dvd just click on mountable drive form my computer.  when you upgrade it takes long time approx 1hour so take time when you upgrade. i know about the other version of ubuntu 13.04 and 12.10 they don't have mountable features.
 tips for ubuntu 10.10 ... http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/ubuntu-tips-and-tricks.htm